InfluxDB Flux - loop columns through fill and sum
Hi I have multiple power sensors and I want to combine all my different loads to one load.
The difficulty is that my sensors do not all send the data at the same time, but only when the value changes.
I have already found the fill function that I can use to achieve this.
I have managed to get all my time steps with the pivot function.
Now I just have the problem that I don't know how to run these functions through my columns.
Programming it hard is not good, as I currently already have 9 values with similar labels and these are increasing.
Additionally, I don't automatically have values from all of them because they don't need to change over a period of time.
Getting the data:
from(bucket: "home_assistant/autogen")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "W")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.entity_id =~ /em3_egl/ and r.entity_id =~ /total/)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  // Columns = friendly names for an easier call
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
    _time: r._time, // time(v: 0), // r._time für Zeitreihe
    _field: r.friendly_name,// strings.trimRight(v: r.friendly_name, cutset: "_"),// _test,//
    _value: r._value
    }))

Merge the data in a list so that one value can be inserted per timestamp:
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_1 phase a active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_1 phase b active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_1 phase c active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_2 phase a active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_2 phase b active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_2 phase c active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_3 phase a active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_3 phase b active power", usePrevious: true)
  |> fill(column: "EM3_EGL_3 phase c active power", usePrevious: true)

Sum data, although this does not work either:
//|> map(fn: (r) => ({ sum: r.["EM3_EGL_1 phase a active power"] + r.["EM3_EGL_1 phase a active power"] + r.["EM3_EGL_1 phase a active power", ...]}))

My goal would be to have the columns used to use the fill and sum functions for these.
